# Python re.sub isn't working in a for loop passing multiple arguments to the function

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to change multiple string values within a single string by defining a function that passes arguments to re.sub via a for loop.

For some reason when I pass the arguments into re.sub, it has no effect on the string, but if I run the exact same syntax outside of the loop with single argument the regex perfroms as expected. Am I missing something here?

```
import re

#This is my function:

def mult(string, *args):

    for arg in args:

      result = re.sub(arg, '', string)

    return result

path = 'file://Volumes/MyDrive/iTunes/Music.mp3'

print(mult(path, '\'file:/\'')) 
#produces no change to the string


#This is the normal re.sub which works fine:

print(re.sub('file:/', '', path))
```

Comment: Try `print(mult(path,'file:/'))` Always clean your strings when you pass to regex. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
import re



def mult(string, *args):

    for arg in args:

      result = re.sub(arg, '', string)

      return result

path = 'file://Volumes/MyDrive/iTunes/Music.mp3'

print(mult(path, 'file:/')) 
#Notice the change to the args. Your string is wrong.
```

Yields:

```
/Volumes/MyDrive/iTunes/Music.mp3
```